# Custom routes with Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I am using Rocket_Pants gem to provide API access for my existing Rails app. I have the following in my Routes:

```
  # HTTP routing 
  resources :posts do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
  end

  # API routing
  api :version => 1 do
    resources :posts, :only => [:index, :show]
    resources :posts do
      collection do
        get 'search'
      end
    end
  end
```

My json API request to `posts/` and to `post/:id works`. However, json API query to `localhost:3000/1/posts/search?query=my_query`doesn't.

(Note: http request to `localhost:3000/posts/search?query=my_query` works).

How should I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should be redefining the `:posts` resource within the `api` block multiple times.

```
api :version => 1 do
  resources :posts, only: [:index, :show] do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: it seems that your solution works (i.e., I got a different error). Could you explain why defining `:posts` multiple times causes trouble?

Comment: I don't know enough about Rails routing internals to give you a solid answer. **[here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/378ea96905e5f95be1a413b7bdd6fbb000265129/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L1238)** is the method definition. What I can tell you is the multiple definitions like that is unnecessary and untidy; both reasons alone for not doing it. If it additionally isn't allowed by the routing mapper, all the more reason to clean your code :)